# Should I use a separate database for every user?

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin, backend

I'm a front end developer building a back end system. Woho!

The system is built on php and html and will be used by at least 500 people. They will all store hundreds or thousands of items in the system. Each item having multiple variables and functions connected to it.

Can they all share the same database? Or do I need a separate database for every user? How much can a regular mysql-database handle?

Comment: There are situations where you might want separate databases (enterprise-y software where the extra time/effort may be worth the safety and data separation). Yours doesn't sound like one of them.

Comment: I am currently running distributed database with around a billion records - and the data structures are poorly designed.  A poorly designed database will cost you far more than a technology decision.  It's very difficult to answer an open ended question.  In any case, there is no way I would go for the overhead and maintenance issues that will arise from separated schemas per user.

Answer (score 0):

There's no reason to separate such a system to several database. When you see the performance start degrading you can consider sharding your database, but until then you're probably prematurely optimizing.